# Save setlocal settings with mksession

Tags: vim

Sometimes when I use vim, I need to change some local settings for certain buffers via `setlocal`. Later, when I save and restore a session with `mksession` and `source`, these settings are not saved and I need to `setlocal` them all again.

This is very inconvenient. So is there a way to keep local settings with a session?

Comment: This is related to a recent question on superuser:  http://superuser.com/questions/721569/how-to-save-open-closed-folds-in-vim-with-mksession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to change the `'sessionoptions'` value. From `:h 'sessionoptions'`:

> Changes the effect of the `:mksession` command.  It is a comma
>       separated list of words.  Each word enables saving and restoring
>       something:
>
> `localoptions`      options and mappings local to a window or buffer (not
>               global values for local options)

Ergo:

`:set sessionoptions+=localoptions`